# RStudio changes order of text and images (for pagination purposes?) when producing a PDF from RMarkdown

Tags: pdf, pagination, r-markdown

On my machine, I have an RMarkdown document that looks something like this:

````
---
title: "My title"
author: "Me"
date: "October 6, 2017"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
Block of text here, call it text A.

![My caption](myimage.png)

Block of text here, call it text B.
````

The intent here is to have text A, then image, then text B.

If the pagination happens to work out so that it would go

1. text A
2. large blank space till new page because image cannot fit
3. new page
4. image
5. text B

I will instead see this as the PDF output:

1. text A
2. text B
3. new page
4. image

However I do not want it to change the order of things in this way. HTML output does not behave like this, which makes sense, since it doesn't do pages. Weirdly, if I set `fig_caption` to `no`, that also seems to make it stop behaving like this. But of course I want the captions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTex automatically chooses the best place to put an image. You can use the `float` package with the option `H` (for *here*) in order to force the image to be placed right where it is in the source. Check this example out:

````
---
title: "My title"
author: "Me"
date: "October 6, 2017"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{float}
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
Block of text here, call it text A.

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics{myimage.png}
\end{figure}


Block of text here, call it text B.
````

Comment: Thanks! How do I center the images using this method?

Comment: Is there a more recent solution to this "floating" problem?  Seems that a very basic rendering process would keep the order of content.